# ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG open app

Tags: android, headset

I have played with the ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG intent a lot now and not come anywhere.. 
What I am trying to do is that when a headset is plugged in to the phone then should a third party app open! Could anyone give me some some examples?

I'm developing for Android 1.6!